# Templating external files in helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to use application.yaml file to be passed as a config map.

So I have written this.

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: ConfigMap
 metadata:
  name: conf
data:
{{ (.Files.Glob "foo/*").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
```

my application.yaml is present in foo folder and 
contains a service name which I need it to be dynamically populated via helm interpolation.

```
foo:
  service:
    name: {{.Release.Name}}-service
```

When I dry run , I am getting this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: conf
data:
  application.yaml: "ei:\r\n  service:\r\n    name: {{.Release.Name}}-service"
```

but I want `name: {{.Release.Name}}-service` to contain actual helm release name.

Is it possible to do templating for external files using helm , if yes then how to do it ?
I have gone through https://v2-14-0.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/#accessing-files-inside-templates
I didn't find something which solves my use case.
 I can also copy the content to config map yaml and can do interpolation but I don't want to do it. I want application.yml to be in a separate file, so that, it will be simple to deal with config changes..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Helm [includes a `tpl` function](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) that can be used to expand an arbitrary string as a Go template.  In your case the output of `...AsConfig` is a string that you can feed into the template engine.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-conf
data:
{{ tpl (.Files.Glob "foo/*").AsConfig . | indent 2 }}
```

Once you do that you can invoke arbitrary template code from within the config file.  For example, it's common enough to have a defined template that produces the name prefix of the current chart as configured, and so your config file could instead specify

```
foo:
  service:
    name: {{ template "mychart.name" . }}-service
```

Answer (score 1):

As best I can tell, there is no recursive template evaluation available in helm (nor in Sprig), likely by design

However, in your specific case, if you aren't expecting the **full** power of golang templates, you can cheat and use Sprig's [regexReplaceAllLiteral](https://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html#regexreplaceallliteral-mustregexreplaceallliteral):

```
kind: ConfigMap
data:
{{/* here I have used character classes rather that a sea of backslashes
     you can use the style you find most legible */}}
{{ $myRx := "[{][{] *[.]Release[.]Name *[}][}]" }}
{{ regexReplaceAllLiteral $myRx (.Files.Glob "foo/*").AsConfig .Release.Name }}
```

If you genuinely need the full power of golang templates for your config files, then helm, itself, is not the mechanism for doing that -- but [helmfile](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile#readme) has a lot of fancy tricks for *generating* the ultimate helm chart that helm will install

Comment: Please accept [David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59877268/225016) as that one is actually accurate; I just didn't see the `tpl` function